# What does AOL mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/AOL

“Cryptocurrencies will disrupt traditional finance because one of their most attractive utilities is the ability to efficiently transfer payment across borders with little to no cost, delay or foreign currency fluctuations. With respect to bitcoin, 50 years is a long time and bitcoin could either become the world reserve currency or the next AOL that made a lot of people wealthy until it was unseated by better technology.”

Source: https://www.cnbc.com/2021/07/03/what-cryptocurrencies-will-look-like-in-50-years.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the first one that your dictionary suggests: "America On-Line (inc)" It is one of the first internet companies that offered connections to general consumers (and not corporations or universities), mostly using "dial up" telephone modems.

It still exists, but has been losing subscribers since 2006, now that dial-up is an obselete technology. A lot of people made money at AOL in the 1990s.